# wordpress get recent posts with description

Tags: php, wordpress

I use Wordpress and I want to get recent posts with thumbnail and description.

So I use wp_get_recent_posts.

```
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);?>
<ul class="main-slider">
   <?php foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){?>
        <li>
            <?php echo '<div class="textoverlay">
                <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '"><h1>' .  $recent["post_title"].'</h1></a>
                    <p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>
            </div> ';
            if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]) ) {
                echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],'thumbnail');
            } ?>
        </li>
        <?php
    }?>
 </ul>
```

I can get post title and link, but I can't get description:

```
<p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>
```

Comment: does those post has `excerpt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just missing of post_id in description without post_id it can't display anything.

```
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);?>
<ul class="main-slider">
   <?php foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){?>
        <li>
            <?php echo '<div class="textoverlay">
                <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '"><h1>' .  $recent["post_title"].'</h1></a>
                    <p>'.get_the_content($recent["ID"]).'</p>
            </div> ';
            if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]) ) {
                echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],'thumbnail');
            } ?>
        </li>
        <?php
    }?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: `get_the_content()` do not expect an ID -> [Documentatio](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo wpautop( $recent['post_content'] );
```